# Android - Picasso load from url

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

I want to try picasso library. But I couldn't run below simple code.

I add picasso with gradle:
    `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26+'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'`

I add internet permission to manifest. `....
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application....`

Sample code:

```
imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
imgView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        String url = "http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png";
        Picasso.with(myActivity).load(url).into(imgView);
        return true;
    }
});
```

imageview in xml file:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:id="@+id/imgView"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    />
```

Loading from drawable folder works. But I cannot see any image loading from url.

**EDIT**

```
imgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("tag", "onClick");
            String url = "http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png";
            Picasso.with(myActivity).setLoggingEnabled(true);
            Picasso.with(myActivity).load(url).into(imgView, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Log.e("tag", "onSuccess");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {
                    Log.e("tag", "OnError");
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

OnClick doesn't work. Logcat is below:

```
02-22 23:08:32.283 21749-21749/? D/Picasso: Main        created      [R2] Request{http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png}
02-22 23:08:32.283 21749-21777/? D/Picasso: Dispatcher  enqueued     [R2]+0ms 
02-22 23:08:32.283 21749-21779/? D/Picasso: Hunter      executing    [R2]+2ms 
02-22 23:08:32.793 21749-21777/? D/Picasso: Dispatcher  retrying     [R2]+509ms 
02-22 23:08:32.793 21749-21781/? D/Picasso: Hunter      executing    [R2]+510ms 
02-22 23:08:33.303 21749-21777/? D/Picasso: Dispatcher  retrying     [R2]+1015ms 
02-22 23:08:33.303 21749-21782/? D/Picasso: Hunter      executing    [R2]+1018ms 
02-22 23:08:33.313 21749-21777/? D/Picasso: Dispatcher  batched      [R2]+1028ms for error
02-22 23:08:33.523 21749-21749/? D/Picasso: Main        errored      [R2]+1232ms 
02-22 23:08:33.523 21749-21777/? D/Picasso: Dispatcher  delivered    [R2]+1231ms
```

**EDIT2**

Someone says that try this link. http://thumbs2.ebaystatic.com/m/mxQFkSjRujUpASIMht_snyQ/140.jpg

It doesn't work for my samsung device. Is it related to response time?

Comment: do u want to click the imageview, and then load an image from the web into it?

Comment: I want to load an image from web. Time doesn't matter.

Comment: what is myActivity? your context?

Comment: try using the error callback to check what if there is a Picasso error. `Picasso.with(getContext())
    .load(url)
    .into(imageView, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onError() {

                        }
                    });`

Comment: @Nerd onError callback triggers. But it doesn't include any information. I don't know why.

Comment: try adding this when you build Picasso instance and see what exception occurs: `Picasso.Builder(getContext())
            .listener(new Picasso.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception) {
                //Here your log
                }
            })
            .build();`

Answer (score 2):

For error logging enable:

```
Picasso.with(Context).setLoggingEnabled(true);
```

And in your code:

```
Picasso.with(this).load("https://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imgView);
```

Another suggestion: in layout xml: Add `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/imgView"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
/>
```

Comment: `02-22 23:05:22.853 21749-21777/? D/Picasso: Dispatcher  retrying     [R1]+508ms 
02-22 23:05:22.853 21749-21781/? D/Picasso: Hunter      executing    [R1]+511ms 
02-22 23:05:23.373 21749-21777/? D/Picasso: Dispatcher  retrying     [R1]+1031ms 
02-22 23:05:23.373 21749-21782/? D/Picasso: Hunter      executing    [R1]+1033ms 
02-22 23:05:23.373 21749-21777/? D/Picasso: Dispatcher  batched      [R1]+1035ms for error
02-22 23:05:23.573 21749-21749/? D/Picasso: Main        errored      [R1]+1237ms 
02-22 23:05:23.573 21749-21777/? D/Picasso: Dispatcher  delivered    [R1]+1237ms `

Comment: remove the picasso code block from `ontouch()`..to `onCreate()`..check if it works there.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the onClick listener instead of onTouch listener:

```
imgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             String url = "http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png";
             Picasso.with(myActivity).load(url).into(imgView);
         }
     });
```

Comment: It is not related to click or touch listener. It triggers onError callback.

Comment: @zumma try to log the touch event..i think that picasso loading statement is getting called multiple times..

Comment: @SantanuSur you are right. But onClick listener is not a solution. It doesn't work too.

Comment: @zumma, can you share the logcat or the error that you have in the onError callback?